# writing the below code and getting following error

Tags: c#

The code is as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine("------no's greater than 20 and divisible by 4 ------------");
{
for (i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
{
    var no = numbers.Where(n => n >= 20 && n % 4 == 0).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(no[i]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Getting the below error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll  Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: You should debug it and see where the error occurs. It's a pretty simple error and I could show you how to fix it. But you'll learn more by debugging, I think.

Comment: You filter your numbers array, so length of the filtered list is probably smaller that the unfiltered list. Yet you loop over the length of the unfiltered list => out of range ... totally expected.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. If one of the answers helped you, you might consider [to mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This shows future visitors of this post that it has a working solution. Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

The `Where` filter returns list of all the matching numbers, which is smaller than the `numbers` list. You need to get the matching numbers before the loop

```
var no = numbers.Where(n => n >= 20 && n % 4 == 0).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < no.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(no[i]);
}
```

Or just use `foreach`

```
var no = numbers.Where(n => n >= 20 && n % 4 == 0).ToList();
foreach (int n in no)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the item from new list `no` that (may) contains less elements then source collection `numbers`. Also, you are filtering source collection on each iteration of the cycle that is not productive.

If you want to filter and print numbers from `numbers` collection that match your condition then you should check this condition for the `numbers[i]` in the loop:

```
Console.WriteLine("------no's greater than 20 and divisible by 4 ------------");
for (i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
{
    if(numbers[i] >= 20 && numbers[i] % 4 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Or using LINQ instead:

```
numbers
 .Where(n => n >= 20 && n % 4 == 0)
 .ToList()
 .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to this code , I prefer put here. i think that's related with your question . It's a list

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 30, 40 };
        List<int> tem = new List<int>();
        numbers.Where(w => w >= 20 && w % 4 == 0).ToList().ForEach(fn =>
        {
            tem.Add(fn);
            Console.WriteLine(fn);
        });
```